# $.getjson not returning object from node.js response.write

Tags: node.js, getjson

I am new to node.js and json and am having trouble returning the JSON object to the client html page that's using `$.getjson`.

In the example below when i point the same code at the api.twitter.... url I can query and return the value. But when I point this to my own node.js back end that's spitting out the same JSON the `alert('inside callback: ' + data[0].is_translator);` does not pop up. What am I doing wrong here? I would really appreciate some help here.

This is script code in my test.html that's calling $.getJSON.

```
<script>
//var url = "http://localhost:5000/searchPlaces?callback=?";
function abc(result) {
//var url = "http://localhost:5000/random"
var url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/21947795900469248/retweeted_by.json?callback=?";
alert('before $.getjson');
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      alert('hello');
      alert('inside callback: ' + data[0].is_translator);
      abc(result.data);
})

}

abc();

</script>
```

---

This is the code from my node.js backend:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var port = process.env.PORT || 8888

function start(route, handle){

        function onRequest(request, response) {

                var postData = "";
                var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

                console.log("Request received for:" + pathname + " receieved.");

          response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
          var otherObject = {"is_translator":false,"id":644233,"followers_count":77};

           response.write(
            JSON.stringify({
              anObject: otherObject
            })
          );
          response.end();

//              route(handle, pathname, response, request);

        }

        http.createServer(onRequest).listen(port);
        console.log("Server had started. Port:" + port);
}

exports.start = start;
```

---

Comment: You said second `alert` is not showing. do you see the first one?
The code you have shown doesn't send the response of type array, so `data[0]` will fail, and you should see an error in console

Answer (score 0):

Callback for `$.getJSON()` is called only if the JSON is valid. The url for your twitter api `http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/21947795900469248/retweeted_by.json?callback=?` gives a JSON with the following error on JSONlint.org

```
Parse error on line 1:
([    {        "is
^
Expecting '{', '['
```

You should maybe $.get() the url and then validate JSON yourself before using it.